# How to go to next slides jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, gsap

I have problem with this code:  [Codepn project](https://codepen.io/GGQa/pen/WNeGmJz)

I would like to see the next section appear every time I scroll down. Meanwhile, only the second one is showing ...

I would also like it to go back to the previous slide using mouse scroll top

the effect I would like to get: [LOOK THIS WEBSITE](https://deepmikoto.com/)

to display I'm using:

```
function handleMouseWheelDirection( direction )
{
    console.log( direction ); // see the direction in the console    

    if ( direction == 'down' ) {

        goNextSlide();        

    } else if ( direction == 'up' ) {

        goPrevSlide();    

    } else {
        // this means the direction of the mouse wheel could not be determined
    }
}
```

**goNextSlide function:**

```
const goNextSlide = () =>{
    TweenMax.to(sectionMain, 2, {x:0, y:-100} );
    TweenMax.to(slide1, 0, {delay:0.4, x:0, y:0, ease: Power4.easeOut, display:"block" } );        
}
```

look at codepen, please, to understand me better. Any ideas? Thanks.

Comment: Hey Simon. I would highly recommend modifying Craig's demo on [this page](https://greensock.com/forums/topic/19393-fullscreen-sliders-horizontal-and-vertical/) as it will solve a *lot* of your issues rather than having to code it up all yourself. In general [the GreenSock forums](https://greensock.com/forums/) are a better place to receive quality help more quickly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you should add an index to identify which section the user is at the moment.

For example something like this:

```
var caseIndex = 0;
const numOfSections = 3;
function handleMouseWheelDirection( direction )
{
    if(caseIndex < numOfSections) {
      caseIndex++;    
    }else{
      caseIndex=0 
    } 

    if ( direction == 'down' ) {
        goNextSlide(caseIndex);
    } else if ( direction == 'up' ) {
        goPrevSlide();

    } else {
        // this means the direction of the mouse wheel could not be determined
    }
}
```

Then when you slide to the next scroll - identified by its index:

```
const goNextSlide = (slideIndex) =>{
    TweenMax.to(sectionMain, 2, {x:0, y:-100*slideIndex} );
    TweenMax.to(eval('slide'+slideIndex), 0, {delay:0.4, x:0, y:0, ease: Power4.easeOut, display:"block" } );
}
```

In my example "`section_main`" changed to "`case_0`"

So this is a basic working for next slides, You get the idea so try to do the same for previous.

Comment: Thank you for your response. I've updated my code and it's better now, but I still don't know how to make scroll top work. The problem is that every time I use the scroll (up or down) the function counts the next index ... What did I do wrong? Could you peek? Here is link to new codepen https://codepen.io/GGQa/pen/WNeGmJz

Comment: @Simon Please follow this one: https://codepen.io/deadlyacid/pen/rNBWMGV

Comment: Perfect. Thank you :)

Comment: do you still have an idea how to block scroll during the animation? now I can use the scroll 100 times and watch the page follow the indexes 100 times ... it would be ideal if the next scroll could be used after the animation.

Comment: Ok, that was Easy, just  if (tl && tl.isActive()) {
        return;
      }